# How to remove an element's attribute in phpunit selenium test?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

Is there anyway to remove an attribute from an element. I don't mean simply setting it to empty string.

For example by removing class attribute:

`<a class='c'>` => `<a>`

I am using selenium 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is not perfect and it executes JS to alter element.

using JQuery:

```
$this->execute(array(
     'script' => "$('#element').removeAttr('class');",
     'args' => array()
));
```